# Debugging - javascript inside show/hide link not working

Tags: jquery, debugging, show

So I have a show/hide link, it works perfectly with text and displays that when I click it but when I tried to put a jquery thing in it so that when I click on it, it will display a text file but it doesn't do that at them moment and instead just displays the text files contents underneath it while when I click on the link that is supposed to show it it shows nothing. 
I have a show/hide link, the html is as follows:

```
   <a href="#" id="hideShow">Title</a>
<div id="message" style="display:none; border: 1px solid #777; width: 500px; padding: 1%;">
blah
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   $("#hideShow").click(function(){
   $("#message").toggle();
  });

</script>
```

And inside that where blah is I want to show the contents of one of my text files and am using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/hello.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
           $('<pre />').text(data).appendTo('body');
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

when I do it with text it works but when I do it with the jquery it is already on the page and doesn't wait for me to click title to show up. I would like to change this

Comment: Your AJAX call is not inside a click handler so its run on load of the page, hence why it is immediately displayed.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan how would I put it inside a click handler so that it wpuldnt immediately show up? What code/script

Comment: In exactly the same way as you have with the `#hideShow` button handler.

Answer (score 0):

Put your ajax call inside the click function:

```
   $("#hideShow").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url : "/hello.txt",
          dataType: "text",
          success : function (data) {
             $('<pre />').text(data).appendTo('body');
           }
      });
      $("#message").toggle();
   });
```

Comment: Hey @ashfaq.p I tried this and it didn't work as intended. The thing still shows up when the page is loaded and then when I click title it opens it again, so that there are two open

Comment: So how could I fix this

Comment: actually I just fixed that, but each time I click title it shows up again so there will be multiple ones can u help me with that?